# Styling React Native elements to display end-to-end

Tags: css, react-native

I'm trying to find a way to style my React Native output so each line follows consecutively from the last. My code below uses a regular expression to divide a sentence into sections.

```
function Test() {
    const text = "Jackie Chan is one of the [1] martial artist of all [2]."

    // Split the content string into segments
    let segments = text.split(/\[\d+\]/);

    return segments.map((segment, index) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.line} key={segment}>{segment}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    });
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    segment: {
        fontSize: 24
    },
    options: {
        fontSize: 24
    },
    line: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'green',
    }
})
```

Each section would eventually have a button dynamically inserted after, but for now, I need each section to only take up the space necessary and for each line to follow immediately after the last, dynamically line breaking when it becomes necessary.But instead they each display on separate lines, show below:

[image]

Since floating is not a thing in React Native, I have tried various flex related styling combinations unsuccessfully. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put `segments.map(...)` inside a View with `flexWrap`, like:

```js
function Test() {
    // ...
    return (
        <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
            {segments.map(...)}
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    outerContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    // ...
})
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/Yo9u6Vdkz)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I appreciate your answer which has helped to resolve my issue. Just one thing, flexWrap did not seem to have the desired effect. Infact it seems only flexDirection:row is the only thing that made the desire change. Still, I thank and give you the credit.